# How to replace duplicates with string and keep only first element in the list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
my_list = [
     ['common1', '112', '4000'],
     ['common1', '11', '11'],
     ['common1', '33', '33'],
     ['common1', '33', '900'], 
     ['common2', '31', '400'],
     ['common2', '2', '2666']
]
```

I want to convert this list into

```
 [
    ['common1', '112', '4000'],
    ['', '11', '11'], 
    ['', '33', '33'],
    ['', '33', '900'], 
    ['common2', '31', '400'], 
    ['', '2', '2666']
 ]
```

Here what I want is replace the `common1` with empty string '' and keep only the first value. Similarly for `common2` value.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is the outer list always sorted as in your example?

Comment: Is the list sorted on the first element of the inner lists? If not, what logic would you apply? Is it merely a change of value or do you need to group values together?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes it is

Comment: OK @schwobaseggl that makes it easier. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
def replace_duplicate(my_list):
    prev_val = ''

    for lst in my_list:
        if prev_val == lst[0]:
            lst[0] = ''
        else:
            prev_val = lst[0]

my_list = [
    ['common1', '112', '4000'],
    ['common1', '11', '11'],
    ['common1', '33', '33'],
    ['common1', '33', '900'], 
    ['common2', '31', '400'],
    ['common2', '2', '2666'],
    ['common3', '115', '5000'],
    ['common3', '12', '15'],
    ['common1', '222', '6000'],
    ['common1', '55', '66'],
    ['common1', '77', '99']
]

replace_duplicate(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ['common1', '112', '4000'],
    ['', '11', '11'],
    ['', '33', '33'],
    ['', '33', '900'],
    ['common2', '31', '400'],
    ['', '2', '2666'],
    ['common3', '115', '5000'],
    ['', '12', '15'],
    ['common1', '222', '6000'],
    ['', '55', '66'],
    ['', '77', '99']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simple and easy solution

```py
def remove_sec_dups(data):
    seen = set()  # keep track of first seen values

    for sub in data:  # get sublists
        first = sub[0]  # get first item
        if first in seen:
            sub[0] = ''  # empty
        else:
            seen.add(first)  # add this to our seen list

remove_sec_dups(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

This outputs `[['common1', '112', '4000'], ['', '11', '11'], ['', '33', '33'], ['', '33', '900'], ['common2', '31', '400'], ['', '2', '2666']]`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for the general unsorted case, too:

```
seen = set()
for i, (head, *_) in enumerate(my_list):
    if head in seen:
        my_list[i][0] = ""
    seen.add(head)
```